# How to fire event on page refresh

Tags: jquery

The back end dev for our site has a div.errors for form handling, it is always present but empty unless there is an error in form submission. Its easy enough initially hide the div and then to check if it has length, if it does display it.

```
if ($(".errors").text().trim().length) {
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
}
```

The issue is this, on page load the div.errors is empty and hidden. when you submit the form, with an error the div.erros then has length, but the page is refreshed (loaded again) and the event does not fire again. Is .live a viable option?

Comment: If you don't want to page to be refreshed you can use AJAX to submit data to the server.

Comment: set error variables from server side language if they have error, if not, dont set them

Comment: elclanrs, Jashwant - both very good ideas, which I will bring up. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this` stops referring to the element:

```
$(".errors").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().trim().length) {
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, really appreciate it. Thx, would have taken me days to figure that out, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Live is not an option here, live is used when you add elements dynamically to the page . You need some kind of state management technique to preserver the value of the div.errors between the page refresh. I suggest you use cookies as they can be accessed easily in JQuery.